# Traversing a tree by name c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, traversal

I've been beating my head against the wall on this for a few hours. I have no idea what to do. I've restructured my function several times, and still haven't gotten it to work correctly.

This is for a programming assignment in my c++ class. It has to have a specific form, as in datatype, arguments, etc, as given by the instructor, so I can't change anything like that. We have to use character arrays, hence strcmp(). we have to return the person if we find it, or NULL if we don't.

Heres what i'm working with so far:

```
person *classname::getPersonByName(char *name, person *rt)
{
    if (rt != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(rt->Title, title) == 0)
        {
            return rt;
        }
        else
        {
            getPersonByName(title, rt->left);
            getPersonByName(title, rt->right);
            //return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

In debug, it will find and return the person just fine by name. The problem is, is that it will promptly overwrite my return, and therefore not end up with the correct correct person.

the NULL at the bottom that is commented out ends up setting every call to NULL regardless of whether the search finds it or not.

Comment: What is `title` and why is `name` unused?

Comment: here's a hint: why does the function have a `person *` in the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, you are not returning anything from the recursive call.

The idea is nothing difficult in fact, just translate this psuedo-code:

```
// This is mostly a procedural way from your method signature, though you are using C++...
Node getPersonByName(Node node, String name) {
    if (node is null) {
        return null
    }

    if (node.name == name) {
        return Node
    } 

    Node result = getPersonByName(node.left, name);
    if (result is not null) {  // found in node.left
        return result;
    }

    result = getPersonByName(node.right, name);
    if (result is not null) {  // found in node.right
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I will leave it as a homework for you to translate this to C/C++, and make the structure looks better by avoiding multiple points of return

Comment: Thank you very much. recursion just kind of makes my head spin a bit. I have a feeling I won't be able to stop thinking this through until i get it.....i'm just OCD like that. :D

Comment: I remembered I read on joelonsoftware.com that, he said there are some kind of people will never be able to get pass through the "Recursion" and "Pointer" barrier even they tried for years.  I wish you are not those kind of people  ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the recursion to work you need to return the value obtained from the calls to the function. Besides it looks like you are mixing title with name.

```
person * foundPerson = NULL;

else
{

     foundPerson = getPersonByName(title, rt->left);
     if(foundPerson != NULL) return foundPerson;
     return getPersonByName(title, rt->right);
     //return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this(Firstly , compare with name that you pass (I assume that is what you want to do , and secondly , your recursion is written wrongly , when recursing down the left and right subtree , `Person*` will be returned to the parent calling function and you have to return it there too.) :

```
person *classname::getPersonByName(char *name, person *rt)
{
    if (rt == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (strcmp(rt->Title, name) == 0)
    {
        return rt;
    }
    Person *left = getPersonByName(name, rt->left);
    if(left!=NULL )
        return left;
    Person *right = getPersonByName(name, rt->right);
    if(right!=NULL)
            return right;
    return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: that if statment at the end there.....if true, then what? or does it matter? ahh, ok, i see it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `title` into your recursive calls and for your string test.  Should you not be using `name`?  I assume that `title` is the name at the current node.

What is the class `classname` for?  Surely you would have done something like:

```
person * person::findByName( char *name );
```

Comment: You should have added this as a comment since you aren't really answering the question.

Comment: yeah, it should. i changed the nature of the problem, and left that part out on accident. the original assignment is for a library, not a person, and you search for books by title. my b. classname is library.

Comment: @jskiles1 well actually it was just a bad answer.  I figured the issue was that the wrong thing was being tested, without noticing that the return value is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done a tree search, but there be some logic such as
transverse the tree.  A tree will have all values less than on the left side of the tree and values greater than on the right side of the tree.  This is pseudo code.  You might want to look up an algorithm for traversing a tree.

```
while rt!=null
if name ==rt-> name return rt
else if name < rt->name then rt=rt->left //otherwise name is greater so on right side     

else rt=rt->right
end while
```

name not found